# Sylvester's sequence: is there an exact closed form?

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form

I'm afraid this is one of those "amateur mathematician with no journal access" questions. Anyhow, Wikipedia ([here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_sequence#Closed_form_formula_and_asymptotics)) and OEIS give this closed form for the terms Sylvester's sequence:

$S_n = \lfloor E^{2^{n+1}} + \frac12\rfloor$ (where $E \approx 1.264$).

Is this the best we can do for a closed form, or is there an exact formula known? Is it known that there is no such formula?

Answer (score 1):

To quote that Wikipedia article (emphasis mine):

> This **would** only be a practical algorithm if we **had** a better way of calculating $E$ to the requisite number of places than calculating $s_n$ and taking its repeated square root.